# Compare and analyze sent and received vectors

Tags: c++

I have a set of connections and protocols for which I am writing unit tests. Their purpose is to assess 2 vectors for validity and consistency; that is there must be not any elements that have been lost, received out of order or are invalid.

**Vector to send is always sorted**.

I came up with a naive function to make such an analysis, but I do not think it is efficient at all (for relatively small amounts of data it is ok).

So, my questions basically are:

1. How can it be improved?
2. What additional analysis may be required to compare sent and received vectors? Are there any cases I have missed?

```
template <typename DataType>
struct io_arrays_compared
{
    std::vector<DataType> sent,
        received,
        validElems;

    size_t invalidOrderElems = 0;

    int verbosityLevel = 0;

    size_t invalid_elems() const
    {
        return received.size() - validElems.size();
    }

    // may be negative
    int elems_lost() const
    {
        return (int)sent.size() - (int)received.size();
    }

    size_t out_of_order() const
    {
        return invalidOrderElems;
    }

    bool Success() const
    {
        return !invalid_elems() &&
        !elems_lost() &&
        !out_of_order();
    }

    operator bool() const
    {
        return Success();
    }

    template<typename Char>
    friend std::basic_ostream<Char> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char> &os,
                                                io_arrays_compared<DataType> ioResult)
    {
        size_t bytesReceived = ioResult.received.size() * sizeof(DataType);

        os << "Transferred: bytes " << bytesReceived <<
           '/' << ioResult.sent.size() * sizeof(DataType) << ", elements " <<
           ioResult.received.size() << '/' << ioResult.sent.size() <<
           "\nLost: " << ioResult.elems_lost() <<
           "\nInvalid: " << ioResult.invalid_elems() <<
           "\nOut of order: " << ioResult.out_of_order() << std::endl;

        // TODO: element by element comparison if verbosity level is not 0

        return os;
    }
};

template <typename DataType, typename CmpLess = std::less<DataType>>
io_arrays_compared<DataType> make_io_arrays_compare(std::vector<DataType> sent,
                                                    std::vector<DataType> received,
                                                    CmpLess cmpLess = CmpLess())
{
    auto cmpEqual = [&](const DataType &d1, const DataType &d2)
    {
        return !cmpLess(d1, d2) && !cmpLess(d2, d1);
    };

    io_arrays_compared<DataType> res;

    res.sent = std::forward<std::vector<DataType>>(sent);
    res.received = std::forward<std::vector<DataType>>(received);


    std::vector<DataType> sortedReceived{res.received.cbegin(), res.received.cend()};
    std::sort(sortedReceived.begin(), sortedReceived.end(), cmpLess);

    // valid elems
    std::set_intersection(sortedReceived.cbegin(), sortedReceived.cend(),
            res.sent.cbegin(), res.sent.cend(),
            std::back_inserter(res.validElems),
            cmpLess);

    res.invalidOrderElems = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != res.sent.size() && i != res.received.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (cmpEqual(res.sent[i], res.received[i]))
            continue;

        // is received element valid?
        auto found = std::find_if(res.validElems.cbegin(), res.validElems.cend(),
                [&](const DataType& d)
                {
            return cmpEqual(d, res.sent[i]);
                });

        // element is valid, but not equal to ith sent, therefore is out of order
        if (found != res.validElems.cend())
            ++res.invalidOrderElems;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Basic unit test for comparison function which is passed:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{

    std::vector<int> out{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
            in{0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 12, 3, 4, 8, 9};

    auto result = make_io_arrays_compare(std::move(out), std::move(in));

    std::cout << result;

    if (result.elems_lost() == 0 &&
        result.out_of_order() == 4 &&
        result.invalid_elems() == 1)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the vectors have to be moved to the result structure? Shouldn't it just work with const references? Or even better let the make function only work with const references and let the structure only contain the sizes and other numbers that are product of the analysis? The structure has no need to contain the entire vectors...

Comment: @slepic the result structure stores vector in order to print report with element by element comparison (to file or to the console), though this feature is not yet implemented (hence there is a TODO: comment). So I use forwarding in order to move vectors if I want to or copy them.

Comment: Oh i see. You should use const references then. Moving the vectors to the result leaves the original vectors in an undefined state. Since this is only analysis i would assume the originals are to be consumed somewhere else. Which they cannot if they have been moved.

Comment: @slepic they are not needed elsewhere in this particular case, so I use move. But the function to analyze uses forwarding (that is I expect, I hope I did it right), so I do not need to use const reference as argument (otherwise I won't be able to use move)

Comment: I mean the properties of the struct to be const references (well of course the make function arguments too). You will have to pass those references in constructor. But I dont see a reason to move them, they are treated as constant...

Comment: @slepic well that makes sence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Naming

Your names are inconsistent. First, there is a mix of camelCase, PascalCase and snake_case. Pick one style and stick with it. You can make an exception for template type names, typically you would write `T` for the data type, and `Compare` for the comparison object.

Second, the three getter functions in `io_arrays_compared` are named `invalid_elems()`, `elems_lost()` and `out_of_order()`. Two have `elems` in the name, but one has it in front, the other at the back. Try to be consistent. Is it necessary to have "elems" in the name or is it clear from the context? If it's clear, then just write `invalid()`, `lost()` and `out_of_order()`. To make it clear that this returns a count, and not a boolean or a vector with the affected elements, I would prefix them all with `n_`, as that typically means "number of": `n_invalid()`, `n_lost()`, `n_out_of_order()`.

The class and function names could be improved too:

- `io_arrays_compared` -> `io_array_comparison_result`
- `make_io_arrays_compare()` -> `compare_io_arrays()`

## The result class should not hold unnecessary data

The result class should just contain four member variables:

```
const size_t n_sent;
const size_t n_invalid;
const size_t n_lost;
const size_t n_out_of_order;
```

If you make them `const`, you can then make them `public` and don't need any getter functions for them. You can still have the convenience functions such as `bool Success()`, `operator bool()` and `operator<<()`.

You shouldn't keep a copy of the sent and received data, because the caller of `compare_io_arrays()` already has that data. Furthermore, `validElems` is just a temporary vector used in `compare_io_arrays()`, so that should just be declared locally in that function.

Even if you plan to make use of the extra data in the future, it is best not to add currently unused member variables. Plans might never be turned into action, or they might change. The [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) applies here. It also makes it harder for code reviewers to know what to ignore.

## Avoid copying the input vectors

It's usually good practice to take `const` references to large parameters such as the `sent` and `received` vectors, so you avoid making unnecessary copies, so write:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
io_array_comparison_result<T> compare_io_arrays(const std::vector<T> &sent,
                                                const std::vector<T> &received,
                                                Compare comp = Compare())
{
    ...
```

If you want to use `std::set_intersection()`, you still need to make a copy of the received data though:

```
auto received_sorted = received;
std::sort(received_sorted.begin(), received_sorted.end(), comp);
```

But that might not be necessary:

## Avoiding sorting the received data

It's possible to avoid sorting the received data, which can improve performance if there are only few packets that are reordered. Since the `sent` vector is already sorted, you can check for each element in `received` if it was present in `sent` using [`std::binary_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search). This has complexity O(N log N), which is the same as first sorting the input and then using `std::set_intersection()`. But you can do better, since you can scan linearly through `sent` and `received` as long as their elements match, and when they don't you can start doing the binary search, until they start matching up again.

## How to count out of order elements

Your method of checking whether elements are received in the same order as they are sent is too naive. It just checks whether elements at the same index in both vectors are equal. But what if one element is lost?

```
std::vector<int> out{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> in {0, 1,    3, 4, 5};
```

In this case, it will report that three elements are out of order. A better approach would be to just scan `received` and check whether successive elements are ordered as expected. For example:

```
std::vector<int> out{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> in {0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5};
```

Only the pair `4, 1` is not in the right order, since `4 < 1 == false`. And that makes sense, since it's just the element `1` that has skipped three places ahead.

## Additional analysis

What I am missing is a check for duplicated elements. This is not an uncommon issue in networks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have mentioned in the comments to my question the reason why I hold vectors instead of just numbers of elements. That is for report printing which will show element by element comparison, marking rows with lost or corrupt elements. I was suggested to store const reference in the result structure.

Comment: I know that using `std::endl` is considerably slower, and I use it here only once - at the end to explicitly flush the buffer.

Comment: @Emma: yes, there is no law against mixing different styles, and indeed some style guides advocate using one style for types, another for function names, so they are easy to distinguish. Google's style guide is just one of many, there is not a single authority. But indeed all of them want you to be conistent :)

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: the [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) applies to the vectors you stored. About using `std::endl` only once: why do you need it at all? When printing to a console or terminal window, it will automatically flush after a newline character, there is no need for an explicit flush.

Comment: @G.Sliepen CLion does not show any output until flush is called explicitly or `std::endl` is passed. And I do need that report, I just haven't implemented it yet

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Ah, if your environment needs the explicit flush, then indeed keep it. But about the unimplemented report: you still should avoid including things that you are not currently needing. It also makes code reviews easier if we don't have to keep track of what unnecessary things were meant for future features.

Comment: About checking the received array for order: successive element being larger then current does bot mean it is in right order. `0 1 15 16 2 3 4 5...`. And there is only `operator<` available. So how can you deal with it? Moreover, if received array has duplicates, what is the right way to get rid of them in order to assess the order in a proper way?

Comment: If it's not in the right order then there will be at least one element in the received array which is smaller than the previous element. In your example, 2 is less than 16. As for duplicates, you can create a `std::set`, and first check if a received item is already in this set. If so, it's a duplicate, otherwise you insert it in the set.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a short review to complement the nice one already posted by G. Sliepen.

### Use only the allowed forms of `main`

The code currently includes this line:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
```

However, there are only two forms of `main` allowed by the standard:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // note no const!
int main()
```

### Consider calculating a Levenshtein distance

A [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) calculation would probably yield a much more concise way to express what went wrong.  By calculating and then traversing a Wagner-Fisher matrix, you can very concisely describe the minimum number of insertions, deletions and substitutions that could have transpired to produce the observed result.